# Why Azure FHIR server? Are there "technical" differences?

Tags: azure, fhir-server-for-azure

I have a general question related to the Azure FHIR server. Specifically, are there "technical" reasons to use it to store electronic health records (EHR)?

People told me major healthcare providers are using FHIR server to store EHR. I understand the business reason. But, technically, Azure cloud is HIPAA compliant. Anything stored and run in Azure is HIPAA compliant. So, if there are other ways such as SQL Server and Data Lake to store EHR, why do we have to store them in FHIR server?

Another reason I ask this question is that my team feels it is not efficient to store EHR via API calls, and it is difficult to query data in JSON format for reporting. So, they feel if Azure is HIPAA compliant they would prefer to store EHR in SQL Server or Data Lake for ease of data management. Both also provide role based security to limit unauthorized access with encryption.

No sure if I miss anything. Can anyone tell me the "technical" differences / advantages of storing EHR in FHIR server? Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

FHIR is primarily for health data interchange using more modern formats such as JSON, so you don't necessarily have to store the EHR data in FHIR format; you can instead have a layer that transforms your EHR data (in SQL or any other format you prefer) to FHIR format (JSON/XML/RDF) as and when needed.

Without a modern standard like FHIR, for the most part, it is very costly and time consuming to design and develop "interfaces" for healthcare data interchange;

Does that help clarify the "technical" need for FHIR?

Comment: I understand the data exchange need of FHIR so I stated as a business need in my question. But, FHIR and JSON are difficult to query. So, they are not the best format for storage and query. There is where I feel no technical advantage to store data in FHIR and JSON format.

Comment: The FHIR standard does provide search capabilities so not sure how far true the statement that 'FHIR and JSON are difficult to query' is, see https://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html. The advantage of storing your data in JSON FHIR or XML is perhaps better performance since there is no additional 'work' done to transform EHR data from it's native form into FHIR JSON/XML 'on the fly'. Sure it sounds like data duplication but I would think of it as a 'specialized data warehouse' for your EHR data

Comment: My team just asked me a question the other day about the search. It is limited to the keywords listed in the link you provided. If they want to find out how many patients having certain medical condition by age and doctor office, it is very difficult. There are many data analytical questions that the basic search just cannot support.

Comment: An update from my team: They found a link talking about [custom search parameters](https://smilecdr.com/docs/fhir_repository/custom_search_parameters.html) in a product called Smile CDR. It's a workaround but still takes a lot of work and not very focused. If I want to search a term "value", this term could mean different things in different context. Compared to table data, the search / query is still way inefficient.

Comment: I recommend heading over to https://chat.fhir.org, there you can network with folks who may be able to better advise you in terms of your advanced search requirements. Also checkout this 2018 FHIR DevDays presentation on FHIR Search - https://www.devdays.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/DD18-EU-Alexander-Zautke-Searching-in-FHIR-resources-2018-11-14.pdf